# java AudioInputStream AudioSystem.write to pipe length error

Tags: java, jruby, processbuilder, javax.sound.sampled

Trying to pipe an AudioInputStream I got from a libary to this process:

```
oggenc - -o wtf.ogg
```

via

```
AudioSystem.write(audio, AudioFileFormat::Type::WAVE, process.getOutputStream());
```

gives me the error:

```
IOException
stream length not specified

file: com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter.write(WaveFileWriter.java)
line: 129
```

So it seems audio stream length needs to be specified. This is a 44.8 kHz stereo PCM format audio with no length specified. **I got this from a library so I can't modify their code.** I tried creating another AudioInputStream from this stream, but I couldn't find a proper length. So how can I specify the length ?

Comment: Where is your code and what exact exception it throws? What is `AudioFileFormat::Type::WAVE`? This is not Java syntax.

Comment: I believe you but there is not sufficuent information. Actually, you don't need to specify length if you have correct audio stream.

Comment: I will try to paste whatever information I can find

Comment: What is the type of `audio` variable?

Comment: For example, while constructing `AudioInputStream` you can pass `AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED` as the length of the stream.

Comment: Yes, I found your error source here, http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/media/sound/WaveFileWriter.java.html

Comment: *"I tried creating another AudioInputStream from this stream, but I couldn't find a proper length"*  combined with *"I got this from a library"* suggests that library is broken & producing invalid sound streams. *"so I can't modify their code."* So find a library that is ***not*** broken & closed source.  I suggest to try Xuggle or Jffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found that you are reading `audio` from somewhere unknown, and then trying to write it into `WAV` format. But `WAV` format requires to write header, which should contain file length. Anyway `WaveFileWriter` throws exception if feeded by stream without knowing length.

I guess your direction is `Java -> oggenc`.

So, you are to learn `oggenc` and know if it accepts headless `WAV` stream. If so, then just pass your `audio` to output stream, without processing with `AudioSystem.write()` which is for headed `WAV`s

According to here http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/oggenc1.html you are able to accept `RAW` with `oggenc`.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to solve the issue with length if you reimplement AudioSystem.write method. It doesn't work with stream and WAVE format because of data length in the header. You should write audio data to some array and then prepare correct WAVE Header. Example: [How to record audio to byte array](http://privateblog.info/kak-zapisat-zvuk-na-java-v-byte-massiv)